# Alignment with Android Spannable on Arabic diacritics

Tags: android, arabic, diacritics, spannable

I am working on a dictionary for Arabic-Turkish. I want to make colorful my diacritics with spannable. It is working but diacritics' vertical alignment changes. This is my layout.

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivFavori"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ivFavori"
                android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
                android:onClick="@{() -> handlers.onHeaderClick(arapcaModel)}"
                android:bufferType="spannable"
                android:text="@{arapcaModel.lemma.formatted}"
                tools:text="أُخْرُجْ"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
```

And this is the code where I'm making diacritics colorful.

```
public void setFormat(){
        String birlesik=lemma_vocalized + " - " + lemma_mfiil + " - " + lemma_emir + " - " + lemma_masdar + " - " + lemma_kok;
        formatted=new SpannableString(birlesik);
        formatted.setSpan(new 
        Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("([ً-ٟ])");

        Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(birlesik);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            int start = matcher.start();
            int end = matcher.end();
            formatted.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255,0,0)), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        }
    }
```

[The result is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU2LZ.png)

[If I comment this function result is like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwqqY.png)

How can I solve this?